# Viewpager not working with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

My `ViewPager` is not working correctly. I don't know what's wrong with my code. I am facing some problems with my `Fragments`:

Basically, I have a `Fragment` named `MyListFragment` that has a list and on the click event of list item I move to the second `Fragment` named `FlowersFragment` that has a `ViewPager` with three items(Another three `Fragments`) in it. And i have a `Button` in my `FlowersFragment` and on click of that `Button` i move to  the third screen named `WelcomeFragment`. now i have a problem :

If i go back to `FlowersFragment` from `WelcomeFragment` then it loses some `Fragments` from `ViewPager` after some research i got a solution like use `childFragmentManager` while creating adapter. That is good for my pager all `Fragments` are now showing correctly in my `FlowersFragment` Pager. But if I go back to `MyListFragment` and I click on second or third item of `ListFragment` its showing me exception with NO ACTIVITY.

Here is my FirstFragment named `MyListFragment`

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment{

private View view;
private FragmentManager fm;
private FragmentTransaction ft;
private ListView listviewPlaces;
private FloristAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<FloristItems> items = new ArrayList<FloristItems>();
private FlowersFragment frag;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container,false);
    listviewPlaces = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listviewPlaces);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        FloristItems florist = new FloristItems();
        florist.away = "3 miles away";
        florist.title = "Florist Flowers";
        florist.price = "$45";
        items.add(florist);
    }
    adapter = new FloristAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), items);
    listviewPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);

    listviewPlaces.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            if(frag == null){
                frag = new FlowersFragment();
            }
            handleFragments(frag);              
        }
    });

}

private void handleFragments(Fragment fragment){

    fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}

}
```

Here is my `FlowersFragment` class that have view pager with containing three fragments:

```
public class FlowersFragment extends Fragment{
private View view;
private FragmentManager fm;
private FragmentTransaction ft;
private ViewPager pager;
private Button btnSendThatFlower;
private FlowerPagerAdapter pageAdapter;
private WelcomeFragment welcomeFrag;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose_flower_buyer, container,false);

    pager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    btnSendThatFlower = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnSendThatFlower);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    pageAdapter = new FlowerPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    btnSendThatFlower.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(welcomeFrag == null){
                welcomeFrag = new WelcomeFragment();
            }
            handleFragments(welcomeFrag);
        }
    });

}

private void handleFragments(Fragment fragment){

    fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}   }
```

Here is my pager Adapter class:

```
public class FlowerPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

private ArrayList<Fragment> pagerItems;

public FlowerPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    pagerItems = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    pagerItems.add(FlowerImage1.getInstance());
    pagerItems.add(FlowerImage2.getInstance());
    pagerItems.add(CustomFlowerFragment.getInstance());

}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int num) {
     if (num == 0) {
         return new FlowerImage1();
     }
     else if(num == 1) {
         return new FlowerImage2();
     }
     else{
         return new CustomFlowerFragment.getInstance();
     }
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pagerItems.size();
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    //super.restoreState(state, loader);
}}
```

`FlowerImage1` `FlowerImage1` `CustomFlowerFragment` are fragments with only `imageview`.

This is my last fragment `WelcomeFragment`

```
public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment{

private View view;
private FragmentManager fm;
private FragmentTransaction ft;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_write_note_buyer, container,false);

    return view;
}}
```

when i am pressing back press then its not showing fragments in viewpager but after swipe on view pager its showing only first or sometimes last pager fragment.

Comment: We cannot help you with no code nor stacktrace.

Comment: @Emmanuel please check my codes.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same issue ended up adding following code inside fragment adapter.

```
@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    //super.restoreState(state, loader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also faced with the same problem, but i fixed it by extending "FragmentStatePagerAdapter" instead of FragmentPagerAdapter. for your case,it would be:

```js
public class FlowerPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

private ArrayList<Fragment> pagerItems;

public FlowerPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    pagerItems = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    pagerItems.add(FlowerImage1.getInstance());
    pagerItems.add(FlowerImage2.getInstance());
    pagerItems.add(CustomFlowerFragment.getInstance());

}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int num) {
     if (num == 0) {
         return new FlowerImage1();
     }
     else if(num == 1) {
         return new FlowerImage2();
     }
     else{
         return new CustomFlowerFragment.getInstance();
     }
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pagerItems.size();
}
}
```